# bind the data of two widgets on the same level to each other and also to a global model through provider

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

### Goal

I'm trying to use a top-level provider to pass model data downstream.
Also, I want some widgets on the same level share that model and affect each other at the same time, without using `setState()`.

### Code

Here is what I do to bind a Slider to a TextField

[image]

```dart
class NumberEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  var data = 0;

  NumberEntry({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NumberEntry> createState() => _NumberEntryState();
}

class _NumberEntryState extends State<NumberEntry> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var model = context.read<Model>();
    return Row(
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: Text('Suffix'),
        ),
        SizedBox(
            width: 50,
            child: TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
              ],
              onChanged: (input) {
                var model = context.read<Model>();
                model.setSuffix(int.parse(input));
              },
            )),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: Slider(
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  value: model.suffix.toDouble(),
                  onChanged: (input) {
                    var model = context.read<Model>();
                    model.setSuffix(input.toInt());
                  })),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

My model looks like this

```dart
class Model extends ModelBase with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  int suffix = 0;

  void setSuffix(int sx) {
    suffix = sx;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

### Expectation

I expected that both widgets can bind to `model.suffix` and affect each other upon interaction. They also affect `model.suffix` independently.

### Observation

The Slider does not move at all. The TextField does not affect the Slider.

### Workaround

I had to bind `widget.data` to the TextField's `controller` and Slider's `value`, then use `setState()` to update them simultaneously in the `onChange()` callbacks to make it work as expected.

### Question

The workaround seems a lot of redundancy right there, i.e. three copies of the same data.

Is this by design, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `var model = context.watch<Model>();`  have you try this?
`watch` and `read` is different when action to the changenotifier

Comment: and also, i always add `key: UniqueKey()` to the widget to make sure the flutter rebuild when there's a changes to the state

Comment: Nope. Correct me if I'm wrong, please: `context.watch()` and `context.select()` can only be used inside the `build()` function. `.read()` is the only way to use it in a widget callback.